# how to know webkit line clamp is actived

Tags: css

Excuse me
   I use `-webkit-line-clamp` attribute to hide extra text when necessary.
   Now I have a button for click to show extra data when it is hidden. how can I know when to show the button?
   Can anybody help me, thanks!

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8auT.png)